# Как изменить переменную с помощь функции в python?

Tags: python, django, redis, task, celery

**tasks.py**

```
from .service import sk

item = {}

@app.task
def poe():
    global item
    item = sk()
    return item
```

**celery.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'poeproject.settings')

app = Celery('poeproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'poe-new': {
        'task' : 'benefit.tasks.poe',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5')
    }
}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .apps import price_info
from .tasks import item
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(f'<h1>{price_info}//////////{item}</h1>')
```

Почему то переменная item не перезаписывается хотя поступают новые данные

Comment: item = sk() что это?

Comment: Я хотел перезаписать переменную item с помощью моей функции которая создает словарь с нужными данными

Comment: переписать или дополнить?

Comment: просто переписать
я при этом создаю переменную пустую но она почему не переписывается и там просто 0 данных когда я перекидываю ее в другой файл

Comment: декаратор @app.task походу не работает, поэтому всегда item = {}

Comment: декаратор работает и я могу наблюдать за его работой в консоли
Как мне сказали item меняется но изменения не передаются в файл тк это не ссылочный тип данных

Comment: дебагер или принтуйте места где надо оследить я в django не силен